# Retrieve some JSON data in SQL Server from linked server openquery

Tags: json, sql-server, postgresql, openquery

I am trying to retrieve some particular data in MS SQL Server using openquery to PostgreSQL.

That table in PostgreSQL have one field with JSON data.

```
select * from  openquery  ( PG_DOCTORCASH_PRODUCTION, '
select
id as webappid
,created_at+interval ''8 hours'' as webapp_created_dttm
,response_body::json->>''status'' as status

from terrasoft_logs 
where type like ''Terrasoft::Clients::CreditInformation%''
and response_body::json->>''status'' in (''3'', ''4'', ''1005'',''13'')


and item_type = ''Client''
and status_code = ''200''
and cast (updated_at+interval ''8 hours'' as date) >= cast(now() at time zone ''utc''+interval ''8 hours'' as date)-interval ''30 days''
limit 100')
```

It all goes right, but when I want to the grab field that placed in some element of JSON(nested), it all goes wrong.

I am wondering how to take data using syntax like used above

```
,response_body::json->>''status'' as status
```

But using the similar syntax doesn't help me(below).

```
response_body::json#>>''{data,10}''
```

Please write me operator that can do it. I think I can dig in the JSON tree only using operators.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution like this

```
response_body::json->''data''->0->>''contact_id''
```